# Openvpn client block the connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openvpn, connection

I tried to get my rootserver use an vps.
I have vps-unlimited and start it with:

```
sudo openvpn --client --config /etc/openvpn/bla@bla.DECB1.ovpn
```

After I used this command, I can not connect to the server via normal ip(and got disconnect (ssh)).

**What is my mistake?**

```
client
dev tun
reneg-sec 0
persist-tun
persist-key
ping 5
ping-exit 30
nobind
comp-lzo adaptive
remote-random
ns-cert-type server
route-metric 1
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
bla
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
remote dk.vpnunlimitedapp.com
proto udp
```